# A square is cut into three equal area regions by two parallel lines find area of square.

Tags: geometry, puzzle

A square is cut into three equal area regions by two parallel lines that are 1 cm apart, each one passing through exactly one of two diagonally opposed vertices. What is the area of the square ? [image]

Comment: Is this a stock image or did you change the problem from 1cm to 6in?

Comment: @DavidPeterson. No "1 cm " is true.i edited.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork . I think we can draw this in $\mathbb{R^2} $ and use integral.  But I can't find a square with this property.

Comment: HINT. Draw a diagonal of the square and consider the four triangles thus obtained.

Comment: @amirbahadory: You must show your own efforts to get answer(s).

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|129.5144), amir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Let $AE=x$. By symmetry (equal area etc.) $FC=x$. Let the side of square be $a$. Then $DE=BF=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$.

Area of the parallelogram $FBED$ = $\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \cdot 1=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$.

Area of $\triangle DAE$ = Area of $\triangle FCB$ = $\frac{ax}{2}$.

$$\frac{ax}{2}=\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \implies \color{red}{x^2=\frac{4a^2}{a^2-4}}.$$

And area of square is thrice the area of the triangle gives us
$$a^2=\frac{3ax}{2} \implies 2a=3x.$$
Solve these to get $a^2=13$ (area of the square).